# Global minimum and convexity

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For differentiable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, saying that $f$ has only one same local extrema $f(x)$ is equivalent of saying $f$ is quasiconvex (concave). But for higher dimensional domains this statement is obviously not true, as quasiconvexity (concavity) is a much stronger statement.

My question is, what kind of convexity is equivalent of saying $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ has only one local extrema point? It is not "semi" or "pseudo" convexity (concavity).

Comment: The function $f(x) = 0$ is quasiconvex but it has more than one local minimum, so the first sentence in the question does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Good point. I supposed to speak clearer that all local extrema have the same $f(x)$ value